# .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 download link?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, frameworks

I want to download .net framework 3.5 sp1 to install on client computer (just ramework not full VS package), as because its needed to run .net 3.5 applications.

I got this link from google: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en

I am not loading "Full Package" given on this page below. But I am not understanding that why this package is of "235 MB" because previous version of framework, .net 2.0 was only of 30 MB around. Then why new version is so heavy? or I am downloading some wrong version.

Please tell me I am downloading the correct .net 3.5 sp1 framework EXE or not. If not please provide me the correct link.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't know where you're starting from, so it's a full cumulative update. That's why it's so big. It's all the patches to go 2->3->3.5->sp1. It'll just use what it needs to.

Comment: Yups, I think that is why its huge :) Thanks

Comment: If you download the bootstrapper it should only then download what you need.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, it's correct. It's huge.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Service_Pack_1)

If you download the stub, you'll still have to download it per client. So you may as well grab the lot now.

Answer (score 1):

The [link you've posted is correct](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en). The web-installer says it has a Download Size of 2.8 MB.
Once you run this, it will download all that is required to update to .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

I'd have expected about 200MB personally as there have been a number of improvements since [.NET Framework 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0856EACB-4362-4B0D-8EDD-AAB15C5E04F5&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

The full setup contains all possible patch variations for both x86 and x64 platforms.

The web setup will only download about 70MB on most systems.